# Draw a trapezoid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So I want to draw a trapezoid like this one:

[image: Trapezoid]

I know how to draw rectangles and triangles, so my basic knowledge of drawing a shape is there, but I don't know how to make this specific shape.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried so far? Can you show some code and where you stuck?

Comment: Take a look at the [Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path(v=vs.110).aspx) control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code

```
      <Grid >
        <StackPanel x:Name="stk">
             <Path Data="M15,0 L60,0 75,30 0,30 z" Height="120" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black"  Width="300"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```